# Simulating Taxed Equity Return Series (U.S.)

Tags: equities, python, simulations, tax

I'm looking to learn how to correctly simulate taxes on dividends and capital gains on simulated return series for U.S. Equities with dividend reinvestment.  I understand I will have to keep track of the tax lots individually and model tax optimal sales.

Do any open source (python?) packages or pseudocode exist that track lots and simulate taxes on trades?